# How to customize Magento Transactional Emails

Tags: email-templates, transactional, html

My website is sending emails like this one:

> Hello,
>
> Thank you for your order from Main Website Store. Once your
> package ships we will send an email with a link to track your order.
> If you have any questions about your order please contact us at
> support@example.com or call us at Monday - Friday, 8am - 5pm PST.

It's in HTML and I can't customize everything. How can I insert my website logo in HTML and also is there any other already finished transitional emails that I can insert directly.

Here is HTML

```
<body style="background:#F6F6F6; font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; margin:0; padding:0;">
<div style="background:#F6F6F6; font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; margin:0; padding:0;">
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
<tr>
    <td align="center" valign="top" style="padding:20px 0 20px 0">
        <table bgcolor="#FFFFFF" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10" border="0" width="650" style="border:1px solid #E0E0E0;">
            <!-- [ header starts here] -->
            <tr>
                <td valign="top"><a href="{{store url=""}}"><img src="{{var logo_url}}" alt="{{var logo_alt}}" style="margin-bottom:10px;" border="0"/></a></td>
            </tr>
            <!-- [ middle starts here] -->
            <tr>
                <td valign="top">
                    <h1 style="font-size:22px; font-weight:normal; line-height:22px; margin:0 0 11px 0;"">Hello, {{htmlescape var=$order.getCustomerName()}}</h1>
                    <p style="font-size:12px; line-height:16px; margin:0;">
                        Thank you for your order from Milkywaytshirts.com{{var store.getFrontendName()}}.
                        Once your package ships we will send an email with a link to track your order.
                        You can check the status of your order by <a href="{{store url="customer/account/"}}" style="color:#1E7EC8;">logging into your account</a>.
                        If you have any questions about your order please contact us at <a href="mailto:{{config path='trans_email/ident_support/email'}}" style="color:#1E7EC8;">{{config path='trans_email/ident_support/email'}}</a> or call us at <span class="nobr">{{config path='general/store_information/phone'}}</span> Monday - Friday, 8am - 5pm PST.
                    </p>
                    <p style="font-size:12px; line-height:16px; margin:0;">Your order confirmation is below. Thank you again for your business.</p>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <h2 style="font-size:18px; font-weight:normal; margin:0;">Your Order #{{var order.increment_id}} <small>(placed on {{var order.getCreatedAtFormated('long')}})</small></h2>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="650">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th align="left" width="325" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px; padding:5px 9px 6px 9px; line-height:1em;">Billing Information:</th>
                            <th width="10"></th>
                            <th align="left" width="325" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px; padding:5px 9px 6px 9px; line-height:1em;">Payment Method:</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td valign="top" style="font-size:12px; padding:7px 9px 9px 9px; border-left:1px solid #EAEAEA; border-bottom:1px solid #EAEAEA; border-right:1px solid #EAEAEA;">
                                {{var order.getBillingAddress().format('html')}}
                            </td>
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td valign="top" style="font-size:12px; padding:7px 9px 9px 9px; border-left:1px solid #EAEAEA; border-bottom:1px solid #EAEAEA; border-right:1px solid #EAEAEA;">
                                {{var payment_html}}
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <br/>
                    {{depend order.getIsNotVirtual()}}
                    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="650">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th align="left" width="325" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px; padding:5px 9px 6px 9px; line-height:1em;">Shipping Information:</th>
                            <th width="10"></th>
                            <th align="left" width="325" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px; padding:5px 9px 6px 9px; line-height:1em;">Shipping Method:</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td valign="top" style="font-size:12px; padding:7px 9px 9px 9px; border-left:1px solid #EAEAEA; border-bottom:1px solid #EAEAEA; border-right:1px solid #EAEAEA;">
                                {{var order.getShippingAddress().format('html')}}
                                &nbsp;
                            </td>
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td valign="top" style="font-size:12px; padding:7px 9px 9px 9px; border-left:1px solid #EAEAEA; border-bottom:1px solid #EAEAEA; border-right:1px solid #EAEAEA;">
                                {{var order.getShippingDescription()}}
                                &nbsp;
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <br/>
                    {{/depend}}
                    {{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order}}
                    <p style="font-size:12px; margin:0 0 10px 0">{{var order.getEmailCustomerNote()}}</p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td bgcolor="#EAEAEA" align="center" style="background:#EAEAEA; text-align:center;"><center><p style="font-size:12px; margin:0;">Thank you, <strong>{{var store.getFrontendName()}}</strong></p></center></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Also where should I change this    {{var store.getFrontendName()}}

Comment: So that it will insert my website name automatically. everywhere. now where it says "{{var store.getFrontendName()}}" It inserts MAIN WEBSITE in emails

Comment: ok, I think I changed {{var store.getFrontendName()}} How Should I change website LOGO, no there is nothing on that template.

Comment: Please specify how to do this in Magento 2

Answer (score 2):

1. To change Logo in admin **System**->**Configuration**->**Design**->**Transactional Emails**->**Logo Image** and easily pick your logo image from there.
2. You need to change the store name by updating your store name in admin **System**->**Manage Stores** -> Select your store and update it with your store name(Because for sending transactional mails store name is taken from here).

Comment: Ok fine! If so, you may tick this answer as a right answer.

Comment: Sibhi S, how do I do this in Magento 2?